# Rails Can't generate new project because of 'MAKE'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, makefile

When I try to start a new rails project, I get stuck. It cry's for json 1.7.4. I'm on windows.

```
rails new delete
      create
      create  README.rdoc
.
.
.
         run  bundle install
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using multi_json (1.3.6)
Using activesupport (3.2.6)
Using builder (3.0.0)
.
.
.
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Installing json (1.7.4) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.
        C:/Programozas/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Programozas/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/ge
ms/json-1.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Programozas/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.4/ext
/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.7.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

It drops the same error for gem install json -v '1.7.4' too.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be running within an environment that has software that can understand `make`. Your windows environment appears to have no such software.

It looks like a common way of developing with Rails on Windows is using [RubyInstaller](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller). People here on SO with similar problems *(after 30seconds of Googling)* have fixed issues similar to yours with the **[DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit)** that comes with RubyInstaller, as it provides "... A “sane” environment ... with make, gcc, sh and similar *nix build tools installed ..."

Comment: actually I made a clean reinstall with the ruby installer, and now everything is fine. But as I see, your suggestion was similar, and I agree it. Thy.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 7 (32 bit) and facing this similar issue when I create a new project. 
I ALREADY have DevKit installed in my \DevKit. The error message that I get says:

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
An error occured while installing json (1.7.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.4'` succeeds before bundling.

C:\myrailsproject>gem install json -v 1.7.4
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

Updating gem file to use json 1.7.3 runs everything fine